# How can I incorporate Betrayal at the house on the Hill to my game of supernatural?

Tags: house-rules

In  Betrayal at the house on the Hill you explore a haunted house with characters until the haunt happens and *stuff* gets real.

Whilst playing this board game a friend of mine stated it'd make a great addition to a game of Supernatural. I'm already trying to figure out how to do this, as I'm planing a game of Supernatural and I'd like to take my players into a haunted house or two. I think I'd narrowed down my challenges thusly:

- Find a way to translate the Superanatural traits of **Agility, Stength, Vitality, Alertness, Intelligence and willpower** to **Might, Speed, Knowledge and Sanity**

  - Find a way to handle trait increases.
- Write an individual haunt to play out in the game.
- Allow the players to collect clues to help in uncovering the haunt/solving the haunt.
- Work out how to handle traitors. NPCs or recoverable PCs?

I was wondering if anyone had tried to mix the board game and RPG? What steps did you take to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large part of Betrayal to me, is the betrayal itself.  The one against many, and how you react to that.  As both the heroes, and the traitors.
That said, I think Betrayal could be an excellent intro to the characters.  Some of the betrayals are "mere differences of opinion" in how to deal with things, while others are outright betrayals.  It would be interesting to see how the characters deal with either of those situations.
If the betrayer doesn't get killed, then how or if you bring the character back could be interesting as well.  I've often had one player as a secret antagonist for the party, and it always adds a great twist to the game.  As well as another dimension of how the players can screw with your plans :)
I wouldn't translate any of the stats.  I'd use whatever gaming stats you have for the base game, and then use stuff from the monster manuals, rather then try and translate the monsters.  Otherwise you'll have to test play it quite a bit to make sure you haven't kicked the difficulty up too high.